# How improve vue component?

Tags: vue.js

I have a code:

```
<template>
 <carousel v-if='windowWidth <= 900' 
   :nav='false'  
   :dots='false' 
   :autoplay='true' 
   :margin='15' 
   :loop='true' 
   :items='3'
 >
   <a v-for='(image, index) in images' :key='index' :href='`${image.link}`'>
    <img :src='`${image.logo}`' class='slider__item'>
   </a> 
 </carousel>
 <carousel v-else :items='14' :mouseDrag='false'>
       <a v-for='(image, index) in images' :key='index' :href='image.link'>
  <img :src='image.logo' class='slider__item'>
</a> 
 </carousel>

</template>
```

And want to improve code like this:

```
:items='windowWidth <= 900 ? 3 : 14'
```

But dont like it. How i can add Conditions in props? And I would like to leave only one 'carousel'. Is it possible?

Comment: you can use computed and do all your conditions in there

Comment: @omerS Can u give me example? Im really new with vue :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do something like this.

- Do not duplicate function that you can write once ( check the width )
- Try to not duplicate a component, it works with different data, just change it
- ```
  :href='`${image.link}`' is the same of :href="image.link"
  ```

```javascript
<template>
  <carousel
    :nav="false"
    :dots="false"
    :autoplay="true"
    :margin="15"
    :loop="true"
    :items="carouselItem"
    :mouse-drag="!isMedium"
  >
    <a v-for="(image, index) in images" :key="index" :href="image.link">
      <img :src="image.logo" class="slider__item">
    </a>
  </carousel>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      windowWidth: window.innerWidth
    }
  },
  computed: {
    isMedium () {
      return this.windowWidth <= 900
    },
    carouselItem () {
      return this.isMedium ? 3 : 14
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: what will happen with `isMedium` after a resize event?

Comment: Working fine. Can i change classes with data?

Comment: I updated the example, now isMedium is a computed because the value inside of it ( windowWidth ) can change @wittgenstein

Comment: @Alex What do you mean ? Which classes ?

Comment: @Usatei nvm. :)